# Liberty WebApp Active Directory authentication

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, websphere-liberty

Here is the code of my little test servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SearchResult result2 = null;
    try {
        if (WSSecurityHelper.isServerSecurityEnabled()) {
            String testuser = "myuser";
            String password = "mypassword";

            UserRegistry registry = RegistryHelper.getUserRegistry("LdapRegistry");
            response.getWriter().append("<p>Output: " + registry.getUserSecurityName(testuser) +"</p>");
            response.getWriter().append("<p>Output: " + registry.isValidUser(testuser) +"</p>");
            response.getWriter().append("<p>Output: " + registry.isValidUser(registry.getUserSecurityName(testuser)) +"</p>");

        }else{
            response.getWriter().append("<p>Output: No Sec Enabled</p>");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        response.getWriter().print("<p>Exception caught: " + e + " </p>");

    }
}
```

And here is my LDAP config from my server.xml:

```
    <ldapRegistry baseDN="o=appsdir" bindDN="cn=user123,ou=usersbind,o=appsdir" bindPassword="mostsecurePW" host="localhost" id="drd" ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" port="389" realm="LdapRegistry" recursiveSearch="false" returnToPrimaryServer="true">
    <ldapCache>
            <attributesCache size="4000"/>
            <searchResultsCache resultsSizeLimit="1000" timeout="600ms"/>
    </ldapCache>
    <activedFilters userFilter="(&amp;(objectClass=person)(|(uid=%v)(samAccountName=%v)(userPrincipalName=%v)))"/>
</ldapRegistry>
```

I think my problem is that the userFilter in the server.xml is somehow of.
When I set it to the following:`

```
(&amp;(objectClass=person)(|(uid=%v))) <-- on purpose to clarify what was removed
```

I get the output:

```
Output: uid=testuser,ou=testing,ou=people,o=appsdir

Output: true 

Output: false
```

But when I add `(samAccountName=%v)` and/or `(userPrincipalName=%v)` to the filter I get the following exception right away:

```
Exception caught: com.ibm.websphere.security.CustomRegistryException:
CWIML4520E: The LDAP operation could not be completed. The LDAP naming 
exception javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 
- Search is not indexed]; remaining name 'o=appsdir'; resolved object 
com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@254ba79e occurred during processing.
```

Why is it not working while using `|` (OR)? I thought this would go through this filters until one matches. Is there some documentation on how this works?

What does `Search is not indexed` from the exception mean?

Btw. using the standard value for the userFilter also results in the same exception.

Comment: You might get better/more direct feedback with using the same filter in ldapsearch. I could find no hint of an AD feature that "rejected" filters/searches that required searching non-indexed fields but that's sure what is seems like!

Comment: Thank you, but the info I got from ldapsearch was the same

Answer (score 0):

So, I played around and with the following filter the `isValidUser` method on a `userSecurityName` works:
`(&amp;(|(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=person))(uid=%v))`
(`amp;` is needed for liberty's server.xml file, otherwise it's not necessary)

I dont know why or how I could check this in AD, but it seems there is no `objectclass=person` when using *userSecurityName*, but there is a `objectcategory=person`.
The same, but the other way around, seems to be true when not using the *userSecurityName*.